# Menu Item Type for My Component com_mycom in Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

I want to add a Menu Item Type for my component.

Have a look at this picture: [image]

How can I add my component to it and add menus to it, so that when a user clicks upon them, they get added at frontEnd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to create new menu item types for your component, you have to create a new xml file. To put it simple, if you want to create a new menu item type for your view "myview" and the layout "default" in you component, usually you have to create a new xml file named "default.xml" inside the folder "/components/com_mycom/views/myview/tmpl" (note the xml file has to be created in the frontend part of the component, not in the administrator).
You can take a look at other xml files, for example com_content/views/article/tmpl

I hope it helps!

Comment: You can find exemple here : http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_%28MVC%29_Component_for_Joomla!2.5_-_Part_08